# Visual Studio 2015 "Find in Files" Always Remembers Find Options

Tags: visual-studio

Every time I open Visual Studio "Find in Files" dialog (Ctrl+Shift+F), it seems to remember some find options that I specified weeks ago. (They are "Look at these file types: *.cs)

I usually have two instances of Visual Studio running simultaneously.

On several occasions, I have closed both instances, and restarted my laptop.

But even in fresh instances of Visual Studio, after a system restart, (Ctrl+Shift+F) remembers my previous find options.

Please can someone point me in the direction of being able to correct this?

Thanks in advance.

Ryan

Comment: I might be wrong, but if you already did some unsuccessful googleing on the topic I'd say there's no way of achieving this without serious work (like searching/editing the VS config files)

Comment: It's gotta be a recent update or resharper update or something.  I never had this problem until recently, it always defaults to *.cs when I launch a new instance of visual studio which really kills searching since a large portion of my solution isn't a cs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens in the latest Visual Studio 2017 as well, and clearing registry suggested for older editions doesn't work. My workaround is to set the file type to `*.*` instead of clearing it, then search so that the new all file types search is remembered.